# Memory management for a class

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

in the following code, How - in terms of memory management - is `class A` allocated and deallocated in .NET (C#).

```
class A
{
    public static m1(int x, int y)
    {
        int x, y;
        return x+y;
    }
    int m2(int p, int q)
    { 
        int p, int q;
        return p+q;
    }
    int x=10; 
    int y;
    const int x=10;
    readOnly y=20;

    public int x
    {
        get {y}
        set {y=value}
    }
}

class B
{
    A a=new A();  // what happens when initializing class A;
}
```

Note: that the usage of `class B` could be either the entry point of the program, or an object instance, but the scope here is on memory management and allocation of the instance of `class A`.

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample that compiles. You sample above has many issues which makes it very difficult to provide the information you are looking for.

Comment: On what level do you want to know about the allocation? If it is stack or heap based allocation? When the objects is garbage collected? When during execution the allocation takes place? Or what thinks that gets allocated when you do `A a=new A()`? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Albin Sunnanbo:_ Yes i am thinking on every point as u are saying above.

Comment: in general you don't need to know when and where objects are created and destroyed in .NET. The runtime will handle that to you, it makes sure you have the objects created when you need them. In order to learn c#/.NET you should better concentrate on other things, like the difference between static and non static. Classes, interfaces, inheritance, etc.

Comment: Albin Sunnanbo  i was doing the same, but when i was learning static i learnt that memory is allocated at compile time, and when i was learing regarding then i lernt that references are store in stack and object itself in heap from there only all this confusion start and when i red about garbage collector then i became more confused tha'ts why all thee questions are coming in my mind.

Comment: I rephrased the question to remove some of the ambiguity.. this question may be better served as a wiki...

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo, I know you wrote this awhile back.. but "In general" you (all developers) should know the difference between conceptual considerations and practical application.. This is a two fold statement (topic of discussion, and generation considersation) I'm making, because you ought to have known better then making a 'practical application' statement in the context of a topic of discussion that is so clearly for 'conceptual consideration'..

Comment: @AlbinSunnanbo, and the other fold of my statement: both are to be considered, in general.. boxing/unboxing and value/referential considerations directly influence practice (and are to be observed in other's samples). Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you describes allocates a single instance of `A` on the heap when you create a new instance of `B`. So,

```
B b = new B();
```

will allocate two objects: one `B` with the direct call and one `A` as part of constructing the `B`.

The line itself does **nothing** until you create an instance of `B`.

`A` seems to have three fields which are not reference fields, so it does not create new objects on the heap but are part of the `A` instance.

That's roughly all the memory that's allocated in this example.

EDIT:

For purposes of greater clarity - A reference link to an article explaining Stack and Heap, and Memory Allocation considerations:
http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/.net-memory-management-basics/

Comment: and what happens to those methods of Class A will they be allocated in heap and there local variable in stack and class variable will be allocated in heap and static variable and methods will be allocated in stack is it true?

Comment: Static variables are allocated in the heap and methods do not take up space; they are not allocated.

Comment: so methods local variables are allocated in stack and when method finish automatically there stack memory is freed and class non static variables are allocated in heap. Which are freed by GC if CLR and static variables memory are freed after we externally set them NULL. Am i correct let me now ....Now i just don't want to much focus on memory allocation and de allocations

Comment: You know what makes me confuse when i was learning OOPS i learnt that when we creat an object of a class then object holds the reference to methods of that class and also hold class variables of that class then, i learnt that object reference is stored inn stack and the object itself is stored in the heap, so it makes me confuse me that how the methods, and class variables and the prperties are  stored in the heap and how then GC takes care of it that made me all confusion and a big chaos....

Comment: also i learnt that in a class all objects share the methods of that class but creates separate copy of class variables then so again it made me confuse o learn the memory manage ment...if some thing more IMP i am missing to learn concept correctly please elaborate me on this from your own thanks

Comment: The object reference is just a variable. When the object reference is `static`, it's stored in the heap. When the object reference is a local variable in a method, it's stored in the stack. Methods aren't stored anywhere but in code and are part of the signature of a class, so these aren't stored on the stack or the heap. The exception is virtual methods which are part of the class instance just like class fields and are also stored in the heap. Virtual methods need to be stored like this because they need to be resolved at runtime.

Comment: These subjects are quite advanced and you should probably read up on a few articles about memory management in .NET to get a complete picture. It's difficult to provide this complete picture through these answers and comments. Search for ".net memory management" on Google; this will provide you with a lot of information.

Answer (score 1):

When you create an instance of B, the memory is allocated for 1 object with one field of reference type ("A"). Right after that new instance of A is created which causes allocation of memory for object with two "int" fields ("x", "y") and with one field of **TYPE IS UNKNOWN** type.